# Definition of Mean Squared Value Error with respect to action-value functions in Reinforcement Learning algorithms

Tags: reinforcement-learning, approximation

I am referring to page 199 of Sutton and Barto book on Reinforcement Learning available here: [book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)

There the *Mean Squared Value Error* for an vector-parameterized function approximation $\hat{v}(s,\mathbf{w})$ of the true value function of a given policy $\pi$ is defined as

$$\overline{VE}(\mathbf{w}) \equiv \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \mu (s)\left[v_{\pi}(s)- \hat{v}(s,\mathbf{w})\right]^2$$

where $\mu(s)$ is some distribution ($\mu(s) \geq 0, \sum_s \mu(s) =1$) over $\mathcal{S}$.

What would be its definition with respect to action-value approximation functions $\hat{q}(s,a,\mathbf{w})$? Is it correct, by recalling that $v_{\pi}(s)= \sum_a \pi(a|s)q_{\pi}(s,a)$, to define it as

$$\overline{VE}(\mathbf{w}) \equiv \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \mu (s) \sum_{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)} \pi(a|s)\left[q_{\pi}(s,a)- \hat{q}(s,a,\mathbf{w})\right]^2$$